# how to pass the value dynamically for content attribute ::after pseudo element im mui styled

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to pass the value from the StyledBox for content attribute ::after pseudo element im mui styled as below,

i know to show the contebnt we have to   give like this :

content: '"some content"',

But that "some content" i want to be variable

```
const SecondColumn = (props: Props) => {
   
    return (
        <Grid item >
            <StyledBox amount={selectedLoan?.principalRepaid} >
                <some code............../>
            </StyledBox>
        </Grid>
    );
};

const StyledBox = styled(Stack)<{ amount?: number }>(({ amount = 1000 }) => ({
  
    '& .chart-label': {
        '&::after': {
            content: '"`${amount}`"',
            // backgroundColor: 'red',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '65%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }
    }
}));
```

Thanks in advance

```
            content: '"`${amount}`"',
```

i tried this, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It was simple

```
content: `'${amount}'`,
```